# Detecting image load on server

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I am wondering how services like mailchimp detect email opens

I read it's because they add a 1x1 pixel image

Can someone tell me how this is done on my server ? I am using AWS :)

I would also like to know how these services detect things like device and browser/email client

Answer (score 1):

> I read it's because they add a 1x1 pixel image

True

> Can someone tell me how this is done on my server ? I am using AWS :)

The usual approach is to set the image source attribute to a URL on your web server that includes a query string parameter that you can track back to a particular user, for example a hash of the user's email address or their ID in your system, e.g. in the email you send you add a tag like this

```
<img src="http://example.com/track?id=42 width="1" height="1" />
```

That forces the email client to load the URL http://example.com/track, which would return a 1x1 transparent image and also log that the ID 42 requested that image.

Note that some email clients block images from some domains. If the user has you in their contacts list, chances are pretty good the image will be shown. Some ISPs will consider your sending reputation, your implementation of email security standards (e.g. SPF/DMARC) and other factors in deciding whether to actually request and display the pixel data.

Comment: I am a little confused about the return image. Would the return image just be a return "<img..." in a function that is called on load? and the rest of the function processes things?

Comment: No, the HTML in the email has the `<img ... />` tag in it. The server returns an actual image, but using e.g. a .php or .aspx page. Edited my answer to make that clearer. Do you have a web server in your setup? If so what language are you using for the website?