# Laravel Return Image src from server for email

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to detect someone opened their email from me.

Right now I'm using approach put 1x1.gif transparent image.

I followed this link: [Detecting image load on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881340/detecting-image-load-on-server)

My current html:

```
<img src="api.example.com/track?id=1">
```

and my server only return simple response:

```
return response('https://cdn.example.com/images/1x1.gif', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/gif');
```

I've tried change the `return response` to `return response()->json()` but stil fail.

My third tried I just echo it out: `echo https://cdn.example.com/images/1x1.gif`

But it still shown a broken image on the email. I've tried view it without email it return me broken image too. I've tried put the image value directly it works properly (to make sure image is there).

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using:

```
return redirect()->secure('https://cdn.example.com/images/1x1.gif');
```